# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: html, xml, forms

Hey guys I'm getting a strange XML error I just can't seem to find the solution too, can any of you see the error?

Edit: I have added the relative code, The project is a form that validates inputs using basic HTML5 pattern attributes etc.

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/assignment/customer.xml
Line Number 47, Column 81:      <input type="text" id="firstname" maxlength="20" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" required />
                ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" 
    content="This document is about a Pizza meal being offered at a restaurant " />
    <meta name="keywords" content="
    Assignment1 5570891 Restaurant Meal" />
    <meta name="author" content="[Michael Freeman]" />
    <link href= "styles/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="alternative.js"></script>-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="product.js"></script>
    <title> Michael's Pizza Assignment </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Contains the header information that sits on top of the page-->
        <header>
        <h1>
        Order Online
        </h1> 
        </header>
    <!-- The navigation bar and "current" class which is used in the CSS-->     
            <nav><a href="index.html" >Title</a>|<a href="product1.html">Pizza</a>|<a href="about.html " >About Me</a>|<a href="Enhancements.html">Extras</a>   
            </nav>    
    <!-- Contains the information in the top bar of the page, this bar maintains its appearance throughout all pages and informs the user of the purpose of the page-->     
        <nav class="orderbar"><p>
            <a href="customer.html" class="current">Register</a>|<a href="select.html" >Make your order</a>|<a href="purchase.html">Complete payment</a>
            </p>
            </nav>

    <!-- Contains the information in the second bar of the page, this bar maintains its appearance throughout all pages-->          
            <article class="secondbar">
            <h3>Please fill out the following form to register
            </h3>

            </article>


            <section>

            <form id="registerform" method="post" action="http://mercury.ict.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php">
            <fieldset id="person">
            <legend>Customer registration</legend>
            <p><label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="firstname" maxlength="20" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" required />
            </p>
            <p><label for="surname">Surname:</label>
            <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" maxlength="20" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" required />
            </p>
            <p><label for="age">Date of birth:</label>
            <input type="text" name="age" id="age" required pattern="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"  />
            </p>
            <p><label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Your@email.here" required/>
            </p>
            <p><label for="phonenumber">Phone number:</label>
            <input type="tel" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" maxlength="10" placeholder="Mobile number:04xxxxxxxx"         required/>
            </p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Address details</legend>
            <p><label for="address">Residential address</label>
            <input type="text" name="raddress" id="raddress" maxlength="40" requried/>
            </p>
            <p><label for="suburb">Suburb/Town</label>
            <input type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" maxlength="20" required/> 
            </p> 
            <p><label for="state">State</label>
            <select name="state" id="state" required>
            <option value="Vic" selected="selected">Vic</option>
            <option value="NSW">Nsw</option>
            <option value="QLD">Qld</option>
            <option value="SA">SA</option>
            <option value="WA">WA</option>
            <option value="NT">NT</option>
            <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
            </select></p>
            <p><label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
            <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" required/>
            </p>




            <p><label>Delivery Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="daddress" id="daddress" maxlength="40"/></p>
            <p><label>The same as residential address:</label> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkaddress" id="checkaddress" />
            </p>

            </fieldset>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Register" id="submit" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />


            </form>
            </section>

    <!-- The footer which contains a link that allows users to email the author of the page-->          
    <footer><p>Email</p> <a href="mailto:5570891@student.swin.edu.au" >Michael Freeman</a> 
     </footer> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There are no “empty” attributes in XML – `required` is invalid, it has to be of the form `attributename="value"`. Convention for converting empty HTML attributes to XHTML is repeating the attribute name as value, `required="required"`.

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue! For some reason I'm not able to select your comment as an answer though.

Comment: That’s because it was only a comment :-) Added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no “empty” attributes in XML – `required` is invalid, it has to be of the form `attributename="value"`.

Convention for converting empty HTML attributes to XHTML is repeating the attribute name as value, `required="required"`.